# Send Bulk Email to Groups Using SMTP

Tags: c#, sql-server, smtp

Please consider the following:

**1. Departments Table:**

---

```
DeparmentId | DepartmentName 
____________________________
1           | Sales
2           | Finance
3           | I.T
4           | HR
5           | Management
```

### **2. Employees Table**

```
EmployeeId  | EmployeeName  | EmployeeEmail      | DepartmentId
________________________________________________________________
1           | Sarah         | sarah@domain.com   | 2
2           | David         | david@domain.com   | 5
3           | Mark          | mark@domain.com    | 5
4           | John          | john@domain.com    | 1
5           | Arthur        | arthur@domain.com  | 3
```

I want to send an email via `SMTP` to employees belonging to a department group. If this was a database say with 50 employees, I could do a look up function like so:

```
private void EmailEmployeeDepartment(int DeptartmentId)
{
    SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient("HostName");
    MailMessage msgMail = new MailMessage(); 

    if(DeptartmentId == 5)
    {
        var mailCollection = new MailAddressCollection()
        {
           new MailAddress("sarah@domain.com", "Sarah"),
           new MailAddress("mark@domain.com", "Mark")
        }; 

        foreach(var sendMailTo in mailCollection) 
        {
           msgMail.To.Add(sendMailTo);
        }

        msgMail.Subject = "Subject Text";
        msgMail.Body = "Email text";
        msgMail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    }
    else if(DeptartmentId == 1)
    {
        //Map other employees belonging to assigned DepartmentId
    }
}
```

But for a database housing hundreds of employees that need to be emailed periodically as per their DepartmentId in my given scenario - How can I achieve this using `SMTPClient`?

So basically my logic requires that I send an email to all users belonging to a specific department. If I send to `Management` then only `Sarah` and `Mark` should receive the email. This is for my C# Windows Forms Application.

Comment: Why not query the database for all the email addresses of employees in said department (by joining the two tables) and then simply do a `foreach` loop, adding each mail address to your msgMail.To.Add?

Comment: Something to consider. A stored procedure might be ideal for this. Let me fiddle with it and see what I get.

Comment: I have posted an answer. It works. Thanks to you @MihaiOvidiuDrăgoi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Stored Procedure:

   ```
   CREATE PROC spMapUsersToDepartments
   @DepartmentId [smallint]    
   AS
   BEGIN
       SELECT email FROM EmployeesPerDepartment WHERE DepartmentId=@DepartmentId
   END
   GO

   -- To test
   EXEC spMapUsersToDepartments 5
   ```
2. Return list of employees assigned to a department

   ```
   private List<string> GetEmailPerDepartmentGroup(int DepartmentId)
   {
       List<string> result = new List<string>();
       myConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FSK_ServiceMonitor_Users_Management.Properties.Settings.FSK_ServiceMonitorConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
       using (mySQLConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
       {
           mySQLCommand = new SqlCommand("spMapUsersToDepartments", mySQLConnection);
           mySQLCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
           SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@DepartmentId", DepartmentId);
           mySQLCommand.Parameters.Add(parameter);
           mySQLConnection.Open();
           mySQLDataReader = mySQLCommand.ExecuteReader();
           while (mySQLDataReader.Read())
           {
               result.Add(mySQLDataReader["email"].ToString());
           }
       }
       return result;
   }
   ```
3. Iterate through `GetEmailPerDepartmentGroup`

   ```
     private void EmailEmployeeDepartment(int DeptartmentId)
     {
       SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient("HostName");
       MailMessage msgMail = new MailMessage(); 

       foreach (var temp in GetEmailPerDepartmentGroup(5))
       {
           msgMail.To.Add(temp);
       }

       msgMail.Subject = "Subject Text";
       msgMail.Body = "Email text";
     }
   ```